# Verify digital signature on php

Tags: javascript, php, cryptography, digital-signature

I'm signing a message on javascript and then trying to verify on php, however it returns always bad.

Im using this http://cdn9.atwikiimg.com/kurushima/pub/jsrsa/sample-rsasign.html as example for my javascript.

my javascript is

```
function doSign() {
 var rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.readPrivateKeyFromPEMString(document.form1.prvkey1.value);
  var hashAlg = document.form1.hashalg.value;
  var str1 = document.form1.msgsigned.value;
  var str2 = document.form1.msgsigned1.value;
  var res = str1.concat(str2);
  var hSig = rsa.signString(res, hashAlg);
  document.form1.siggenerated.value = linebrk(hSig, 64);
}

function doVerify() {
  var sMsg = document.form1.msgverified.value;
  var hSig = document.form1.sigverified.value;

  var x509 = new X509();
  x509.readCertPEM(document.form1.cert.value);
  var result = x509.subjectPublicKeyRSA.verifyString(sMsg, hSig);

  // display verification result
  if (result) {
    _displayStatus("valid");
  } else {
    _displayStatus("invalid");
  }
}

function copyMsgAndSig() {
  _displayStatus("reset");
  document.form1.msgverified.value = document.form1.msgsigned.value;
  document.form1.msgverified1.value = document.form1.msgsigned1.value;   
  document.form1.sigverified.value = document.form1.siggenerated.value; 
}

function _displayStatus(sStatus) {
  var div1 = document.getElementById("verifyresult");
  if (sStatus == "valid") {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "skyblue";
    div1.innerHTML = "This signature is *VALID*.";
  } else if (sStatus == "invalid") {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "deeppink";
    div1.innerHTML = "This signature is *NOT VALID*.";
  } else {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    div1.innerHTML = "Please fill values below and push [Verify this sigunature] button.";
  }
}
```

And this is my php

```
<?php
        $msgAssinada=$_POST['msgsigned'];
        $msgAssinada1=$_POST['msgsigned1'];
        $assinatura=$_POST['siggenerated'];
        echo "<p>".$_POST['msgsigned']."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$_POST['msgsigned1']."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$_POST['siggenerated']."</p>";

        $fp = fopen("publicCert.pem", "r");
        $cert = fread($fp, 8192);
        fclose($fp);
        $pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public($cert);
        $result = $msgAssinada . $msgAssinada1;
        echo $result;

        $ok = openssl_verify($result, $assinatura, $pubkeyid);

        if ($ok == 1) {
            echo "good";
        } elseif ($ok == 0) {
            echo "<p>bad</p>";
        } else {
            echo "ugly, error checking signature";
        }

        openssl_free_key($pubkeyid);
    ?>
```

and im using this keys:

private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEArS+LAkcvzrv5yICTGrJFkK+Z6uIJ1VizM8Cs8sj1uBYg6R+Z
(...)
9VA6LyRzv11n2wpJ0tOusRv7+XhF+BE28gkEfZtBg9mZakqVH7zO9A==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Public Key

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFfzCCA2egAwIBAgIDDguBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMHkxEDAOBgNVBAoTB1Jv
(...)
Etj7VCXe3h2xHgQUfkUvnRw8vw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: "it returns always bad"? What errors?

Comment: @JensonMJohn I would assume this line: `echo "<p>bad</p>";` gets executed.

Comment: yes, no errors, just returns bad

Comment: Seems like signature is incorrect!